# Listening to events fired from parent components in VueJs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

The concept is to display the image in a Modal(child component) when users click on a particular image from a Collection(parent component). This is my code:

routes.js

```
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Explore from './components/Explore';
import OeModal from './components/OeModal';

export default {
    mode: 'history',

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            component: About
        },
        {
            path: '/contact',
            component: Contact
        },
        {
            path: '/explore/',
            component: Explore,

            children: [
                { path: ':id', component: OeModal, name: 'OeModal', props: true }
              ]
        },
    ]
};
```

Explore.vue (parent)

```
<template>
    <div class="" id="rbGallery">

        <div v-masonry transition-duration="0.3s" item-selector=".item"  origin-top="true" class="flex">
            <div v-masonry-tile class="item w-1/4" v-for="(img, index) in photos">
                <a :href="'/explore/' + img.id" @click.prevent="imgModal(img.id)"><img class="" :src="img.url" alt="Card image cap"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <router-view></router-view>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {

        computed: {
            photos() {
                return this.$store.getters['photos/imgData'];
            }
        },

        methods: {

            imgModal(id) {
                this.$emit('imgClicked', id);

                this.$router.push({ name: 'OeModal', params: {id: id}})
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and OeModal.vue (Child)

```
<template>
    <div>

        <oe-modal name="testModal" width="80%" height="auto" :scrollable="true">

            <div class="px-16 py-8">

                <img class="modalImg" :src="img.url" alt="Sunset in the mountains">

                <div class="text-center m-auto">
                    <span class="inline-block bg-grey-lighter rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-grey-darker mr-2">#photography</span>
                    <span class="inline-block bg-grey-lighter rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-grey-darker mr-2">#travel</span>
                    <span class="inline-block bg-grey-lighter rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-grey-darker">#winter</span>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium animi hic obcaecati neque dolores praesentium perspiciatis sit ea similique, quae tempora in saepe mollitia odio iusto deleniti harum? Quis, in reiciendis fugiat cum corrupti libero m
                        inus sequi asperiores iusto provident fugit tenetur repellendus nisi! Cupiditate magni unde obcaecati nemo exercitationem.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </oe-modal>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.$parent.$on('imgClicked', this.$modal.show('testModal'));
        },

        watch: {
            '$route': function(to, from) {
                // this.$modal.show('testModal');
            },
        },

        computed: {
            img() {
                return this.$store.getters['photos/imgData'].find(i => i.id == this.$route.params.id);
            }
        },

        methods: {
            show () {
                this.$modal.show('testModal');
            },
            hide () {
                this.$modal.hide('hello-world');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, I have set an event `imgModal` from the parent component so that it gets fired each time an image is clicked. I have tried to listen to the event from OeModal (child component) and do some work there but I just can't get it to work. When tried `this.$parent.$on('imgClicked', this.$modal.show('testModal'));`, I got the following error in console:

`[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "imgClicked": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are emitting the event before the component is created and registers to listen for the event. So, instead of this:

```
this.$emit('imgClicked', id);
this.$router.push({ name: 'OeModal', params: {id: id}})
```

try this:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'OeModal', params: {id: id}})
this.$emit('imgClicked', id);
```

or potentially:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'OeModal', params: {id: id}})
this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.$emit('imgClicked', id);
});
```

Also, how you are registering your event handler is incorrect. Instead of this:

```
this.$parent.$on('imgClicked', this.$modal.show('testModal'));
```

try this:

```
this.$parent.$on('imgClicked', function () { this.$modal.show('testModal'); });
```

Comment: Your answer is the exact solution to this thread. Keep up the good work!